# Prove that $u$ is a trivial unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-rings

Let $G$ be a finite group. I want to prove that if $u\in \mathbb{Z}G$ be a torsion  unit (i.e. for some $n$, $u^n=1$) of integral group ring $\mathbb{Z}G$ such that $u$ normalizes $G$,  then $u$ is a trivial unit i.e. $u=\pm g$ for some $g\in G$.

**In simple language** , I need to prove that for a finite group $G$, all torsion units in $N_U(G)$ are trivial (i.e. of form $\pm g$) where $U$ is unit group of $\mathbb{Z}G$

It looked easy, but after several attempts and using known results on units in Integral group rings I was getting nowhere.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: There seem to be some redundancy on the assumptions (the element is both assumed to be central and to normalize $G$, which follows from being central).

Comment: Also, by torsion, do you mean that it has finite multiplicative order?

Comment: yes sorry. Ii mistyped. wait a minute

Answer (score 1):

Let $u$ be a unit of finite order in $N_U(G)$ and $^*$ be the standard involution on $\mathbb{Z}G$.

From *An Introduction to Group Rings* by Milies and Sehgal we need

> **Corollary 7.3.2** Suppose $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}G$ has the property that it commutes with $\gamma^*$. If $\gamma$ is a unit of finite order, then $\gamma=\pm g_0$ for some $g_0 \in G$.

Now, by hypothesis for each $r \in G$ there exists an $s \in G$ such that $u=rus$. Then $uu^*=(rus)(rus)^*=ruu^*r^{-1} \quad \forall r \in G$, i.e. $uu^*$ is central, which implies $ uu^* uu^*=uu u^*u^*$ which in turn implies $uu^*=u^*u$. But now $u$ satisfies the conditions of the corollary, thus $u=\pm g$ for some $g \in G$.